# PHP: How to display select options if no value from database

Tags: php

I am trying to display my dropdown with a value from the database, but if the value is null I want it to show my options.

Currently it keeps showing me the blank select option.

```
<select class="form-control col-sm-5" id="freqlevels" name="freqlevels" value="<?php if ($customerinfo['freqlevel']) { echo h($customerinfo['freqlevel']);} else { echo "" ; } ?>"">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Twice Weekly">Twice Weekly</option>
    <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
    <option value="Fortnightly">Fortnightly</option>
    <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
</select>
```

Please can you suggest what I should do?

Comment: what are you actualy asking? `Currently it keeps showing me the blank select option.` -> that's because you're first option that you've added... is a blank option ... `but if the value is null I want it to show my options. ` where your conditional to check this?

Comment: select tags don't have values either - should be done on your options

Comment: treyBake, I tried this in my value option, but took it off since it didnt work for me. value="<?php if ($customerinfo['freqlevel']) { echo h($customerinfo['freqlevel']);} else { echo "" ; } ?>"

Answer (score 1):

put your condition outside the value

```
<?php if ($customerinfo['freqlevel']) { echo value="$customerinfo['freqlevel']";}
```

hope this will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of conditional statements.

```
<select name="something" id="my-select">
    <option value="0">Everyone can see me</option>

    <?php if (empty($array['some_key'])) : ?>
        <option value="1">I'm only if some_key is empty</option>
        ..etc..
    <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

Then you can check values against the option value:

```
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"
        <?php echo ($key === $_POST['some_key'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>>
    Hello, world
</option>
```